# Iterate through two dimensional array while changing each element

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to fill a two dimensional array with certain values. I want to get:

```
[
  ['Num00', 'Num01', 'Num02'],
  ['Num10', 'Num11', 'Num12'],
  ['Num20', 'Num21', 'Num22']
]
```

How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
game_field = Array.new(3, Array.new(3))
3.times do |i|
  3.times do |j|
    game_field[i][j] = 'Num' + i.to_s + j.to_s
  end
end
game_field
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) accepts a block in which you can define the element directly:

```
Array.new(3){|i| Array.new(3){|j| "Num#{i}#{j}" } }
# [["Num00", "Num01", "Num02"], ["Num10", "Num11", "Num12"], ["Num20", "Num21", "Num22"]]
```

When you call `Array.new(3, Array.new(3))`, you create an array which contains 3 times the exact same object : `Array.new(3)`. When you modify an element in an inner-array, you modify it on every array!

If you initialize `game_field` like this : `game_field = Array.new(3){ Array.new(3) }`, your code works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note that building a `Matrix` is simple because it has an inherent notion of rows and columns:

```
Matrix.build(3){|i,j| "Num#{i}#{j}"}
```

I think the Matrix class is often overlooked. The built-in methods to operate on rows, columns, submatrices, etc, can sometimes be really handy.

Comment: Interesting. Note that you need `require 'matrix'` and possibly `to_a` for the desired format.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity:

```
([(?0..?2)] * 2).
  map(&:to_a).
  reduce(:product).
  each_slice(3).
  map { |e| e.map(&:join).map(&'Num'.method(:+)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
9.times.map{|i| "Num#{i.divmod(3).join}"}.each_slice(3).to_a
```

Comment: `divmod` is definitely the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try

```
game_field = (0..2).map do |i|
  (0..2).map do |j|
    "Num#{i}#{j}"
  end
end
```

One liner

```
game_field = (0..2).map {|i| (0..2).map {|j|  "Num#{i}#{j}"} }
```

Comment: 2.4.2 :002 > `game_field = (0..2).map {|i|(0..2).map {|j| "Num#{i}#{j}" }  }
 => [["Num00", "Num01", "Num02"], ["Num10", "Num11", "Num12"], ["Num20", "Num21", "Num22"]] `
2.4.2 :003 > `game_field
 => [["Num00", "Num01", "Num02"], ["Num10", "Num11", "Num12"], ["Num20", "Num21", "Num22"]] `

Comment: very elegant answer in one line

Answer (score 1):

Ternary numbers?

```
(0...9).map{|n| "Num#{n.to_s(3).rjust(2,"0")}"}.each_slice(3).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Well using Eric and Sawa's answer along with `repeated_permutation` we have

```
[0,1,2].repeated_permutation(2)
       .map { |a, b| "Num#{a}#{b}" }
       .each_slice(3).to_a
```